# Как считать двумерный массив в Си?

Tags: c, массивы, память

Выделяю память для массива. Считываю данные из файла, и у меня либо вылетает, либо нули или непонятные цифры появляются. Запуталась с освобождением памяти... (

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double **A;
int n_A, m_A;
int i, j;

void read_matrix(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    /* m_A - число строк, n_A - число столбцов */
    fscanf(file, "%d %d", &m_A, &n_A);
    A = (double **)malloc(n_A * sizeof(double *));

    if (A != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < m_A; i++) {
            A[i] = (double *)malloc(n_A * sizeof(double));
            if (A[i] != NULL) {
                memset(A[i], 0, n_A * sizeof(double));
                free(A[i]);
            }
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clrscr();
    read_matrix("data 2.dat");
    free(A);
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Alcheringa Не нужно задавать новые вопросы в комментариях: это не соответствует формату форума, потому что запутывает тему. Когда у Вас возникает новый вопрос, нужно открывать новую тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Должно быть: A = (double ** ) malloc( **m_A** * sizeof(double * ));
2. Освобождение памяти free(A[i]); делаете слишком рано, очевидно, что в этой функции вообще не надо освобождать.
3. Для fscanf(file, "%lf", &A[i][j]); должен быть цикл по j, чтобы прочитать все значения

Comment: про цикл по j согласна.
По поводу памяти - у меня массив 30х400 - т.е. мне не хватает места при объявлении double A[m_A][n_A];
Тогда когда освобождать память в функции main ?

Comment: @Alcheringa Памяти в стеке может не хватить, конечно. Освобождайте в main запустите цикл по i до m_A и удалите все, что выделяли A[i], а потом уже сам массив A.

Answer (score 2):

Вы делаете `free(A[i])`, а затем пытаетесь что-то записать в `A[i][j]`, ошибка. Кстати, цикла по `j` вообще нет.
Но я бы посоветовал вам вообще отказаться в этой задаче от динамических выделений памяти, а использовать память на стеке:

```
double A[m_A][n_A];
```

и затем так же, но без `malloc` и `free`. Но это если ваша цель — не научиться выделять память :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//Функция readfromfile (FILE * fp, double ** p, int sz1, int sz2)
//Входящее значение:    FILE * fp  - файл 
//                      double ** p - двумерный массив
//                      int sz1 - строки
//                      int sz2 - столбцы
//Функция построчно считывает файл в массив
void readfromfile (FILE * fp, double ** p, int sz1, int sz2)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<sz1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<sz2;j++)      //Естесвенным образом считываем данные из файла
            fscanf(fp,"%Lf",&p[i][j]);  //в двумерный массив.
}

//Функция create(int sz1, int sz2)
//Входящее значение:    
//                      int sz1 - строки
//                      int sz2 - столбцы
//Функция создает двумерный массив SZ1 x SZ2
//Исходящее значение:   double **   - двумерный массив SZ1 x SZ2
double ** create(int sz1, int sz2)
{
    double ** temp = (double **) malloc(sz1 * sizeof(double *));    //Здесь и далее - некомментируемые 
    for (int i=0; i<sz1; i++)                                      //действия считаются очевидными - и не
        temp[i] = (double *) malloc(sz2 * sizeof(double));        //нуждаются в комментировании.
    return temp;   
}

//Функция erase(double ** p, int sz1)
//Входящее значение:    
//                      double ** p - двумерный массив
//                      int sz1 - строки
//Функция очищает память от двумерного массива
void erase(double ** p, int sz1)
{
    for (int i=0; i<sz1; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: Вот блин) Я тревогу отправил, не прочитав до конца))
Хотя по сути то же самое, что и я написал, только с комментариями.

Comment: Что есть тревога - не в курсе, впервые на портале. Ваш пост не видел на момент написания коммента. Да и комментил скорее из совокупности любопытства "а что вылезет на месте несуществующего аватара на этом портале" и того факта, что у меня на компе хранится кой-чего с первого курса универа :)

Comment: Комментить - добавить комментарий) Добавить ответ несколько другое.
Я сам по началу путался. В отсутствии аватара - выводится граватар. Как вместо него поставить аватар где-то была тема.

Comment: омгомгомг, Серега, ты чтоль?) 2645 же

Comment: ну да

Answer (score 0):

> fscanf(file, "%d %d", &m_A, &n_A);

А не нужно перенос строки добавить в конец?

> fscanf(file, "%d %d\n", &m_A, &n_A);

Например так..

Comment: Без разницы. Разделитель воспринимается как пробел, так и перенос строки...

Comment: Кстати,со сдвигом все в порядке, все правильно переносится.
Остался вопрос: почему с 22 по 32 строки у меня печатаются нули?

Comment: Вы бы выложили ваш входной и выходной файлы, например, на http://pastebin.com/
А то, правда, приходится гадать.

Comment: Ну в общем что-то мне туда не загрузить сейчас...
Короче, получилось так, что через Turbo C получается так,как я сказала. Записывается в выходной файл не полностью, последние числа нули.
Но, если компилировать через Visual Studio, то все как надо.
Т.е. компилятор подвел?.. Не подскажите хороший компилятор для Си?

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не делайте подобную солянку из кода.
Не забывайте про прототипы функций.
Ну и разберите этот код, как оно работает я уже плохо помню, надо будет комментарии написать.

```
double ** Load_Matrix(int * colls, int * rows, char filename[32]){
    FILE * mf;
    int i,j;
    double tmp;
    double ** p;
    if(mf=fopen(filename, "r")){
        fscanf(mf,"[%d;%d]",colls,rows);
        printf("colls: %d\nrows: %d\n",*colls,*rows);
        p=Create_Matrix((*colls),(*rows));
        for(i=0;i<(*rows);i++){
            for(j=0;j<(*colls);j++){
                fscanf(mf,"%Lf ",&p[i][j]);
            }
        }
    fclose(mf);
    return p;
    }
    else
        printf("No such file!\n");
}

double ** Create_Matrix(int colls, int rows){
    double ** p;
    int i;
    p=(double **)malloc(sizeof(double*)*rows);
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        p[i]=(double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*colls);
    }  
    return p;
}

double ** Erase_Matrix(int rows,double ** p){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        free(p[i]);
    } 
    free(p);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Здесь уже совершенно верно сказали об отсутствии цикла по j, но по большому счету
дело не в этом, а в том, что Вы строите НЕ ДВУМЕРНЫЙ МАССИВ, а массив указателей
на массивы с элементами типа double ! В Вашем случае нельзя использовать &A[i][j]. 
Надо писать что-то вроде:

```
{
    double *pd = A[i];
    fscanf (file,"%lf",&pd[j]);
}
```

Если надо делать именно массив (все элементы последовательно лежат в памяти)
то:

```
{
    double **A = calloc(m_A*n_A,sizeof(double));
    double *pd;
    int    i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < m_A; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n_A; j++) {
            // вычислим адрес нулевого элемента i-ой строки 
            // n_A - количество элементов в строке, каждый размером sizeof(double)
            pd = (double *)&((char *)A + i*n_A*sizeof(double));
            // прочтем j-ый элемент i-ой строки
            fscanf (file,"%lf",pd+j);   // в такой записи С-compiler 
                                        // умножит на sizeof(double) сам
        }
}
```

Успехов в (системном) программировании.

Comment: Автор строит именно двумерный массив и использование в scanf'е &A[i][j] вполне правомерно, поскольку нужно изменить это значение. Вы же предлагаете использовать одномерный массив. Что же это тоже допустимо, если вспомнить, что все двумерные массивы в памяти расположены линейно. НО ГЛАВНОЕ - вы совершаете целую серию ошибок. Я даже не стану перечислять их - слишком много.

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться с Вами. Автор выделяет память сначала под вектор адресов *double, а затем в цикле под строки своего 'массмва'. Это не массив double. Насчет & в вычислении адреса начала строки совершенно согласен, это ошибка. Надо: pd = (double *)((char *)A + i*n_A*sizeof(double));

Comment: @avp Автор выделяет память под массив указателей на double, потом в каждый элемент этого массива записывает указатели на массив double. Получает нормальную структуру - двумерный массив. Внимательнее смотрите.

Comment: @avp Как уже сказал у Вас много ошибок. Например, double **A = calloc(...); Что это такое? calloc возвращает указатель, а не двойной указатель! Подучите тему - работа с указателями.

Comment: ОК. 1. calloc() возвращает *void, он автоматически приводится к любому указателю (посмотрите stdlib.h). 2. Вы верно пишете: ...потом в каждый элемент этого массива записывает указатели на массив double.
Но кто гарантирует, что эта память будет выделена последовательно и без промежутков между блоками, выделяемыми malloc()? Более того, в A лежит адрес не первого элемента памяти, выделяемого этой последовательностью malloc(), а адрес указателя на результат первого malloc(), ну а работать A[i][j] в данном контексте конечно будет.

Comment: @avp Вы серьезно не знаете разницы между указателем и двойным указателем или просто это такой прикол - стало скучно и решили поговорить?

Comment: Во первых я очень серьезно рекомендую изучить тему про указатели.
Во вторых, если вы не знаете то двумерный массив именно таким образом в СИ и создается, я очень сомневаюсь что учитель по языкам и системам программирования ошибается в том как надо организовывать память под массив. И еще если вы считаете что это не работает - попробуйте запустить.

Comment: Насчет A[i][j] не работает, погорячился, согласен.
Вектор указателей ссылающихся на вектора значений (в нашем случае
double) это моделирование двумерного массива с целью использования
единообразного синтаксиса (т.е. как при доступе к элементам двумерного массива с фиксированной размерностью). Такой подход допустим, однако при работе с частями массива в подпрограммах неприемлем из-за того что логически смежные элементы массива могут располагаться в несмежных областях памяти. Поэтому лучше сразу ориентироваться на истинное размещение данных.

Comment: Какая разница, если есть указатели на эти области?